# Does casting a char * to another pointer type break the strict aliasing rule when the memory is from malloc?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1) that `char *`- and their signed and unsigned counterparts - can alias any type without violating the strict aliasing rule. However, having a `char *` point to an `int` variable and casting that `char *` to a `double *` breaks the rules because the underlying object is of type `int`. But what if the memory is from `malloc`? For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *buffer = malloc(32);
    unsigned char *ptr = buffer;

    *ptr = 10;
    *((double *)(ptr + 1)) = 3.14;
    *((double *)(ptr + 9)) = 2.718;

    printf("*ptr: %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("*(ptr + 1): %lf\n", *((double *)(ptr + 1)));
    printf("*(ptr + 9): %lf\n", *((double *)(ptr + 9)));
    
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the following:

```
*ptr: 10
*(ptr + 1): 3.140000
*(ptr + 9): 2.718000
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I know the memory from malloc is untyped and can store any data unlike an `int` array which can only store data of type `int`.

I haven't received any warning from gcc but apparently it is not very reliable at warning you when you break the strict aliasing rules. So does my example break them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior due to invalid access by misaligned pointers.

The memory address of the pointer returned by `malloc` is specified to have the maximal alignment so that the address can be used by different types without issues. That's why it is valid to do

```
double* ptr = malloc(42*sizeof(double));
```

On the other hand, it is not guaranteed that `ptr+1` is a properly aligned pointer for `double`. In fact, it is very likely that it is not aligned provided that we know `ptr` itself is properly aligned, as you can see the undefined behavior is reported [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6GK3or7e9).

The next question is, if we change the code so that the pointers are properly aligned, what is the answer to your question.

```
int main(void)
{
    void *buffer = malloc(32);
    unsigned char *ptr = buffer;

    *ptr = 10;
    *((double *)(ptr + _Alignof(double))) = 3.14; //(*)

    printf("*ptr: %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("*(ptr + _Alignof(double)): %lf\n", *((double *)(ptr + _Alignof(double))));
    
    return 0;
}
```

For the above modified code, the behavior is well-defined assuming that there are no out-of-bound access to the allocated buffer. This can be seen from the following quote from the latest standard draft (6.5.6 in https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf):

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is
> the declared type of the object, if any<sup>98</sup>. If a value is stored into
> an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that
> is not a non-atomic character type, then the type of the lvalue
> becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for
> subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value. If a value is
> copied into an object having no declared type using memcpy or memmove,
> or is copied as an array of character type, then the effective type of
> the modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that
> do not modify the value is the effective type of the object from which
> the value is copied, if it has one. For all other accesses to an
> object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is
> simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.

Where footnote 98 says

> Allocated objects have no declared type.

At the line marked `(*)`, we hit the second sentence in the above quotes, and the effective type is fixed to be double for the `double` object that now lives at the address of `ptr+_Alignof(double)`.

The following code after `(*)` would be a violation to the strict-aliasing rules, even if the pointer is properly aligned.

```
int i = *((int *)(ptr+_Alignof(double)));
```

Writing to the memory through a lvalue of a different type is allowed according to the last sentence of the quote above, and the intent is made quite clear by the explicit mention of "subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value". This is in fact the basis of how memory pools work by recycling memories earlier used by other objects and reassigning them for objects with new types. So the following is valid, and updates the effective type of the associated memory. (Assuming that the pointer is properly aligned)

```
*((int *)(ptr+_Alignof(double))) = 42;
```

However, as @JohnBollinger points out in a comment, many of the common C implementations are deficient with regards to the effective type updates via a write similar to the one above. For such implementations, it is possible that they perform incorrect type-aliasing analysis and optimize the code incorrectly. So despite that the C standard states the above is valid, it is probably wiser not to do it directly. The case for memory pool implementation is different as the code that updates the effective type is often located in a different TU and the incorrect type-based aliasing analysis by such deficient implementations cannot do much harm.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't aware that misalignment was UB. Correct me if I'm wrong but if I wasn't using C11 with the alignof keyword would +8 and +16 be the correct way to align instead of +1 and +9?

Comment: It depends on your platform. On x86 it is 4, on x86_64 it is 8. And +8 and +16 can align correctly for both platforms.

Comment: I have one final question. cppreference mentions that the first write would become the object's type for that write and all subsequent reads. Does this mean that if I do another write to the same piece of memory with a pointer cast to a different type, the object would aquire a new type?

Comment: If you mean the case in my updated answer, that is violation of strict-aliasing. If you mean some other ways  of writing, please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear enough. For example if I do this: *(( double* )(ptr+8)) = 3.14; According to the source that you cited, the memory at that location gains the type of double. So I can store values of type double at that location and any subsequent reads would return a value of type double. But is this permanent or can I do this: *(( long long* )(ptr+8))=12; and change the value of that location to type long long and then any subsequent reads would not return a value of type double but rather of type long long?

Comment: The type is permanent. My updated answer already addressed that.

Comment: Alright thank you for the help. I didn't properly read the memcpy part. Although doesn't "Any other access to the object with no declared type, the effective type is the type of the lvalue used for the access." mean that it can change?

Comment: I think I got the memcpy part wrong, so I have removed that from the comment above. `memcpy` cannot change an already fixed effective type, but it can be used to give an effective type to a memory that does not have a fixed effective type yet.

Comment: I don't think the text is defective. The object has no declared type since it was returned from malloc. Even if it might have gained an effective type the object wasn't declared with a type like int x; and thus can be referred to as the object with no declared type.

Comment: After second read of the standard I think you are correct. I think it is valid to change the effective by merely writing to it. I will update the answer again.

Comment: It is worth noting that some widely used implementations are deficient in the area of writes that should modify the effective type of an object.  They may perform type-based aliasing analysis incorrectly on code that performs such writes, so although C says you can, it's probably wiser not to do.  At least, not where the compiler can see you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Merged into the answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: One could argue that the phrase "...and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value" includes read accesses that follow writes that use different types, and that an object which has received contradictory effective types would be forevermore accessible only via character types.  That's the only way I can see for justifying the behavior of clang and gcc.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The only way I know of interpreting the ET rules that would be consistent with clang and gcc behavior but accommodate the possibility of user code recycling storage for use at different types would be to treat the ability to support such constructs as Quality of Implementation issue, and say that clang and gcc should be viewed as "conforming but deficient" when it comes to tasks that would require such recycling.

Answer (score 4):

`*((double *)(ptr + 1))` gives us three things to consider:

1. Does the conversion to `double *` satisfy requirements, particularly alignment?
2. Is the conversion to `double *` meaningful (is the resulting value sufficiently defined)?
3. Is accessing the memory as a `double` defined?

### 1. Does the conversion satisfy requirements?

The type of `ptr`, and have `ptr + 1`, is `unsigned char *`, and C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says “A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type…” Since `ptr + 1` is a pointer to an object type, it satisfies this. The paragraph continues “… If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…” As others have pointed out, `ptr + 1` may not be correctly aligned for the `double` type. It is very likely not optimally aligned, but whether it is “correctly” aligned is a matter for each C implementation. Some support accesses with any alignment, albeit with performance costs. (It is also allowed under the C standard, but not implemented in any C implementation I know of, for `char` and `double` to be the same size, in which case `ptr + 1` would be correctly aligned for a `double`.)

### 2. Is the conversion meaningful?

C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 continues “… Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer…” This is all the paragraph says about conversions to a pointer-to-object type other than pointers to character types. Note that it only tells you the pointer is useful for converting back to the original type. It does not tell you it is useful for accessing objects in the new type.

For example, given `short Array[2]; short *p = (short *) &Array;`, `p` has some value, and it has been converted from the address of `Array` (not, note well, from the address of `Array[0]`). But the standard does not tell us the result of the conversion is the address of `Array[0]`. It could be some value that is meaningless except that converting it back to `short (*)[2]` yields the address of `Array`. For example, consider a C implementation that starts all arrays on 64-byte boundaries, because its hardware does a weird thing with forming 22-bit addresses from two 16-bit values (effectively `(a << 6) + b`), so keeping arrays on 64-byte boundaries means you only need 16 bits to record their addresses, whereas recording an arbitrary `char` address requires at least 22 bits. (There was hardware like this.) When you convert `&Array` to `short *` in this C implementation, it could give you a 22-bit `short *` value in which the 16 bits of `&Array` are not in a usable position for addressing a `short *`. The only use would be for converting it back to `short (*)[2]`.

You will not find this in normal modern C implementations, but it is allowed by the C standard.

Note that if we had this sequence:

```
void *p = malloc(sizeof (short [2]));
short *pShort = p;
short (*pArray0)[2] = p;
short (*pArray1)[2] = (short (*)[2]) pShort;
```

It is technically not defined by the standard that `pArray0` compares equal to `pArray1`. `malloc` is defined to return a pointer that may be assigned to any pointer-to-object type with a fundamental alignment requirement and used to access an object of that type in the allocated space. That tells us `pArray0` points to the allocated space and may be used to access an array of `short` there. But `pArray1` was not converted directly from the pointer returned by `malloc`. It was passed through a `short *`. It is common to assume this works in normal C implementations, and we can reason it is expected, but the C standard does not explicitly guarantee this.

### 3. Is accessing the memory as a `double` defined?

Suppose all of the above are satisfied, so that `(double *)(ptr + 1)` gives us a correctly aligned pointer to space we may use for a `double`. Can we access a `double` there? This is addressed by the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7, which says we may access (read or write) an object using only certain types, notably a type compatible with the *effective type* (which for `double` is just `double`), a qualified version of a compatible type (so we can read a `double` as a `const double`), a character type, and certain other types that do not concern us here.

For directly defined object, as in `double d;`, the effective type is the declared type. For dynamically allocated memory, there is no effective type at first and, whenever you store into it, the effective type is the type you are using. This means that writing into dynamically allocated memory always satisfies the aliasing rules of 6.5 7.

Considering reading the memory, as you do in the `printf`, requires more consideration. Dynamically allocated memory gains an effective type when (C 2018 6.5 6):

- You store into it using a non-character type.
- You copy into it using `memcpy`, `memmove`, or character-by-character from an object with an effective type.

This means that reading the memory as a `double` satisfies the aliasing rules as long as the previous write was as a `double`. They are also satisfied if the memory has no effective type yet, because, for that case, the effective type of a read is the type used for the read. A problem would arise only if you gave the memory some effective type other than `double`, as by writing into it through `uint64_t`, and then tried to read it using the type `double`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. At the end of your answer you mentioned, "A problem would arise only if you gave the memory some effective type other than double, as by writing into it through uint64_t, and then tried to read it using the type double." Does this mean that if the effective type was originally a double due to some access to it, and then I accessed at as a uin64_t, the memory changed effective type or can the effective type given to memory from malloc from the first access not change to another effective type due to subsequent accesses?

Comment: If the effective type is `double`, and you **write** to the memory as a `uint64_t`, its effective type becomes `uint64_t`. That write is defined by the C standard, however then reading it as a `double` is not defined by the C standard. If the effective type is `double`, and you **read** from the memory as a `uint64_t`, that read is not defined by the C standard. You can change the effective type by writing to the memory with a new type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: As interpreted by clang and gcc, if storage is written as type `double` and later as type `int64_t`, any later read using a non-character type may arbitrarily, at the compiler's convenience, treat the storage as having whichever type would be *incompatible* with the read, thus invoking Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Simply converting `int*` to `double*` (whether by a cast or not) doesn't violate strict-aliasing; that's only if you *access* (read and/or write) the object using lvalues of different non-character types (generally by dereferencing a pointer for at least one of them) and your example doesn't do that. (You access byte 0 only as char, and bytes 1:16 only as double. How the memory was allocated doesn't matter.

There is a *different* rule that converting to a more strictly aligned pointer type may <strike>produce an invalid pointer value, and dereferencing it may</strike> cause UB. Here `malloc` (and `calloc realloc`) may differ from a declared variable, because `malloc` etc return memory that is sufficiently aligned for *any* type, whereas e.g. `int x` could allocate memory that is aligned for `int` but not `double`. However `(char*)malloc() + 1` as your example does is almost certainly unaligned for `double` just as much as `&intx` could be. *Most* implementations today do not require alignment (except possibly for volatile), and if the one(s) you use does(do) not, then your example code is fine, although often unaligned access has slightly lower performance and if you do a LOT of it (like trillions) it may make a noticeable difference.

Comment: *There is a different rule that converting to a more strictly aligned pointer type may produce an invalid pointer value, and dereferencing it may cause UB.*  Just creating such a pointer is enough to invoke UB - no dereference is necessary.  [C11 6.3.2.3p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Andrew: You're right it's immediate on the conversion, although I thought I remembered it being delayed. Maybe the neuron for 'one-past-array' took an unauthorized trip elsewhere?

Comment: I assume it's to support hardware that not only has strict alignment requirements but also dedicated registers for pointers, and those registers simply can't handle misaligned pointers.  Recent POSIX and Windows systems, even on hardware with strict alignment requirements, tend to be "pointers are just 32/64-bit values".

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Clang also exploits the fact that such conversions are UB to justify transforming e.g. `struct s1 { char a[2]; }; struct s2 { char a[2]; short z; }; union u { struct s1 v1; struct s2 v2;}; void test(union u *p1, union u *p2) { p1->v1.a[0]=p2->v1.a[0]; p1->v1.a[1]=p2->v1.a[1]; }` into machine code that performs a single 16-bit load and store, even on platforms that don't support unaligned access.  Note that in the code as written, all accesses are performed by `char` reads and writes, which require no alignment, and no code ever uses union member `v2`, but ...

Comment: ...because `v2` requires 16-bit alignment, clang will assume that `p1` and `p2` will always be 16-bit aligned.

Comment: @supercat Ouch.  Hello `SIGSEGV` if clang happens to use SIMD instructions there and the struct's aren't aligned...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I'd thought of the issue as being problematic on low-end ARM chips, but SIMD instructions could cause problems on higher-end systems too.  A bit ironic given the absurd claims by the maintainers of clang and gcc that the Common Initial Sequence rule requires that actions be performed using lvalues of union type.